# The daily paper is compiled at ... , but printed far away

Tags: present-simple

> The daily paper **is** compiled at the editorial headquarters, known as the prepress centre, in the heart of the city, but **printed** far away in the suburbs at the printing centre.

Why does the writer use present simple and past simple in the same sentence? should's he say:

> but **is** printed far away in the ...

Comment: It *is* "is printed," but the writer simply didn't write the second "is" to save space and ink. Also, note that this is not only simple present, but it is passive voice in the simple present tense. If you understand that "is compiled" and "is printed" are passive voice, you will understand why this had been written the way it had been. You may also read this for more information: [parallel construction](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-parallel-construction-correctly).

Comment: There's rule called [conjunction reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955)